# Delete a row (Record) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my code to delete my first row.

But not effected!

```
mysql> select * from myt;
+--------+--------------+------+---------+
| Fname  | Lname        | age  | phone   |
+--------+--------------+------+---------+
| NULL   | Jackson      | NULL |    NULL |
| stive  | NULL         | NULL |    NULL |
| ghbfgf | rtrgf        |   22 |     111 |
| zxas   | zxa          |   30 | 6547812 |
| wewew  | uytree       |   22 |  658478 |
+--------+--------------+------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from myt
    -> Where Fname = "NULL";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks!

Comment: NULL is a type of variable, not a string.

Comment: And even if it was strings should be enclosed in single quotes (for standard compatibility)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `IS NULL`.

You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as `=`, `<`, or `<>` to test for `NULL`.

```
DELETE FROM myt WHERE Fname IS NULL
```

- [Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Answer (score 3):

NULL is not a value.

NULL means nothing is present.

So usage of FNAME = "NULL" is wrong.

```
delete from myt Where Fname IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first row is NULL (none) not "NULL"

Answer (score 1):

NULL is not a value in RDBMS; it is a marker for a missing value.  When you are using "NULL" it denotes a string value. You can simply use "IS NULL". Hope this helps.